# How can I delete all voicemails from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, visual-voicemail

I would like to bulk delete all the voice mails from my iPhone but it appears I need to first delete each one (multiple taps on each message) and then bulk delete them all from the "deleted items" sub folder.

Is there a way to more efficiently delete all voicemail?

*n.b. I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 7 on Verizon that isn't jailbroken but would welcome any answers that work for whatever OS / carrier even if a jailbreak is needed*

Comment: maybe you need to clarify: is it delete forever (from your phone)?

Comment: I want voicemails gone so that when I tap on VoiceMail they don't appear. Is there some other delete you are thinking of @Buscar웃 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient method of deleting multiple voicemails at once on the device is using multitouch to swipe left on multiple voicemails at once, then tapping delete.

If your device is jailbroken, you can delete voicemails from the location that they are stored in (and the SQLite3 database in):

```
~/Library/Voicemail/
```

Answer (score 1):

Via swipe left on multiple voicemails you can delete them, and on the Phone app, you can even "delete all" of them.

But to delete Permanently all voicemails Permanently, meaning could not be recovery by any software, you should try [iMyfone Umate](https://www.imyfone.com/iphone-space-saver/).